# How to add data row to object

Tags: powershell

Below is the result of an API call via Invoke-Restmethod

[image]

And output of $test.result.organizationContext is as follows

[image]

[image]

**How can I add an line item to this "organizationContext" object with values for the different attributes like " name", "id"  ?**

Comment: Please don't post barely legible images of text, but clear text instead - properly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that you already have the values you want to add defined in variables, you can create a new custom object and then effectively, yet inefficiently, add it to the array.

```
$newOrganizationContext = [pscustomobject]@{
                            classificationId = $classificationId
                            group = $group
                            id = $id
                            isGroupSeparator = $isGroupSeparator
                            name = $name
                            objectId = $objectId
                            path = $path
                            subClass = $subClass
                            synchronized = $synchronized 
                            type = $type
                          } 
$test.result.organizationContext += $newOrganizationContext
```